# How to detect a squash operation in git post-rewrite hook?

Tags: git, githooks

I want to perform some operations after a rebase from master, but not upon an interactive rebase (squashes, rewords, etc)

How do I detect what kind of rebase is invoking the `post-rewrite` hook (I already check if it is a "rebase" and not "amend")?

I can get a list of commits in STDIN, but then what?

Comment: In the `post-rewrite` you can do more than just reading commits from stdin: analyze the output of `/proc/$PPID/cmdline` (that differs for non-interactive and interactive rebase thus can be parsed); or check/analyze directory contents for `$GIT_DIR/rebase-apply` (non-interactive) and `$GIT_DIR/rebase-merge` (interactive; the latter directory contains the `git-rebase-todo.backup` file you can parse to check the presence of `s`, `squash`, `f`, `fixup` or any other interactive rebase command) assuming the `GIT_DIR` variable is constructed with `GIT_DIR="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.git"`.

Comment: Wow, this sounds nice, thank you!